# Compose Rotation Matrix from XYZ (Gravity/Acceleration)

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've been playing around with both Matlab & Apples documentation in regards to [CMRotationMatrix](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreMotion/Reference/CMAttitude_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CMAttitude/rotationMatrix) for weeks.

I've found that I could easily re-create [CMRotationMatrix](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreMotion/Reference/CMAttitude_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CMAttitude/rotationMatrix) by calculating it with [Roll, Yaw & Pitch](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreMotion/Reference/CMAttitude_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CMAttitude/roll).

However, I've found no resources/documentation on how to create a Rotation Matrix from [XYZ](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreMotion/Reference/CMGyroData_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/CMRotationRate) rotations from either `gravity` or `userAcceleration`.

All I found was how they create a 4x4 matrix in their [VideoSnake](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/samplecode/VideoSnake/Listings/Classes_matrix_c.html) demo.

So my question is, does anyone have any input of how to create a 3x3 matrix from XYZ rotations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To begin with rotation matrix has vast applications in Physics, Geometry and Computer Graphics according to Wikipedia. Now looking at it from this angle in relation to your question where you made mention of gravity and userAcceleration we are seeing a synergy between principles in relation to physics where we can make mention of spacecraft exploration which depends 100 percent on gravity.

Now getting to the meat of the matter on XYZ rotations in relation to Rotation Matrix there is an abstract figure which is denoted on the origin point of the XYZ axes without any specifics to a particular angle as a starting point.

Now this is the part you have to understand, since we are using abstract and arbitrary figures we need to convert this XYZ axis point into direction vectors which can then be understood in real life world coordinates.

Only then we will be able to synergistically relate Rotation Matrix and XYZ coordinate points

Now to conclude

The essence of using this direction vector is to convert the direction into equivalent direction in cognisance with the rotation matrix which can then be effectively utilised and expressed on the platform-local coordinates

Comment: Makes sense.. How about rotating an existing Quaternion/Rotation Matrix by XYZ coordinate points? <-- Simply just "appending" to the original Quaternion/Rotation Matrix